# Rails, Installed Rails Debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Please see below:

```
$ sudo gem install ruby-debug
Successfully installed ruby-debug-0.10.4
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ruby-debug-0.10.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug-0.10.4...
```

That all looks great, then when I go to fire up the server, it starts up and then exists:

```
$ rails server --debugger
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Silencing Postgres
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
Exiting
```

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your Gemfile to include ruby-debug or ruby-debug19?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to put it in the Gemfile, `gem 'ruby-debug'` and then run `bundle install` on it. Try that